# TypeScript: How to make sure two props of a functional component, which are arrays, have the same length?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a functional component in react which accepts two separate strings as props. Is there a way to make sure that these two arrays must have the same length, using TypeScript? In other words, when we are using this component inside other components, unless the props are the same length, we will receive an error.

To give you a simple example, imagine something like this:

```
export const TableView = ({ s1, s2 }: { s1: string[]; s2: string[] }) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {s1.map((s, index) => {
            return <th>{s1[index]}</th>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {s2.map((s, index) => {
            return <td>{s2[index]}</td>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

I want to make sure I see an error when I use it with strings having different length.

```
      <TableView s1={["1", "2", "3"]} s2={["1", "2", "3", "4"]} />
      {/* show an error here */}
```

Comment: Do you want a *compiler* warning?  Or a runtime warning?  If you want a compiler warning then does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/we0xYW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on failing use cases.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get a compiler warning and the link you've sent works perfectly, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make the compiler keep track of the lengths of the `s1` and `s2` elements of the input parameter, you should make `TableView` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `s1`, and then use that to check `s2`.  The call signature for `TableView` should therefore look something like this:

```
<T extends string[]>({ s1, s2 }: {
    s1: [...T];
    s2: [...{ [I in keyof T]: string; }];
}) => JSX.Element
```

Here we are saying that `T` is some array type of strings, and that `s1` is essentially of type `T`.  The syntax `[...T]` uses [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax to give the compiler a hint that we'd like it to interpet `T` as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and not just an array type.  Tuple types have a known order and length, while plain array types do not.  You care about the length, so you want a tuple type.

It would be nice if we could write `[...T]` for `s2` also, but unfortunately for you, the compiler will tend to infer the elements of `T` as being string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"1"` and `"2"` instead of `string`.  If so, saying that `s2` is `[...T]` would be placing the restriction that each element of `s2` would have to be exactly equal to the corresponding element of `s1`.  We don't want to reject `{s1: ["1", "2"], s2: ["2", "1"]}`, so we can't do that.

So instead we say that `s2` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) with the same number of elements of `s1` but where each value type can be a `string`.

That's the constraint you want.

---

Let's test it:

```
<TableView s1={["1", "2", "3"]} s2={["4", "3", "2", "1"]} /> // error!
// --------------------------➨ ~~
// Source has 4 element(s) but target allows only 3.

<TableView s1={["1", "2", "3"]} s2={["4", "3", "2"]} /> // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCqQA9JY40IA7AZ3gBUUAjAGyQA1YEgDucALxwAPJzh0YSFgBM2cDlGAsA5gG0AugD4AFAG91ARgA06gExwAvgC445thZe6AdD877Sdp4+Xua6AJJwWnAA1kgAnhCYcH4uGlrajvqOAJSShq5UcHBEMACuUCxwxoVFMjC8AoY1tXUAFqjKTZQtLdIwUF09PabuXiAoYMbGbDZaynS5EvmmzUO1JeWVfa2GIxa6c3T6DtIA9DA7FN1rRQ7ZDqu95wOPMuftKJ2vfTwQynGDNZ9F7XG4jWxjCZTGaRFQLPIFUE3YpIMoVOqdcEHOG0Y5nGCdK7InIPJFPfqA8m-f6Ut71fhIQHZK4OK5UU4AKiYrA4yQaQhEohcsnktEUKjUaR0BhMbmsdkcLhWSPcQV8-lWbFsapCcHCsJi8USyX0qX66QCDg1lDuCIAUgBlAAaXgAogIQEp4BzTlQqNJqQC-ddZPzhGJLBJTLoAEQWGM2GO2BNwGMAZhjxzsUdjABYU+mC8nE-Gs6d8qdTvIoDgoABCGqVuAAWlbbfbHc7HcAFeRwAB+fcbVYdEHKaCQcFaKDUufkHq901yPFK8HqUG0qLgKD4fAgojUrD4cTgaa8waKoYZ4fE7hzcaLBYzWa1d-ziYzieTZYrVYg0RQcTBmcgZdFQQA)

Comment: Looks amazing! Thanks for your thorough explanation. Many great points in a single answer, and I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the condition in your jsx like so :

```
export const TableView = ({ s1, s2 }: { s1: string[]; s2: string[] }) => {
  return (
  {s1.length === s2.length ?
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {s1.map((s, index) => {
            return <th>{s1[index]}</th>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {s2.map((s, index) => {
            return <td>{s2[index]}</td>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   :
   <p> Error arrays are not the same length ...</p>
   }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like below before return

```
if(sl.length !== s2.length) {
  throw "Arrays are of different length"; //which throws custom exception
 /*Or you can return anything that suits your needs*/
}
return(
  //here goes your code
)
```